# applescript mysql mamp

Tags: mysql, applescript, mamp

I would like use an Applescript for insert values in a local mysql db.
I'm using MAMP.

I found this for the connection but it doesn't work: (error number -60007)

```
set mysql_db to "my_database"
set mysql_user to "root"
set mysql_host to "localhost"
set mysql_pw to "root"
set mysql_table to "my_table"

tell application "Finder"
    # Start MAMP's Apache server
    do shell script "/Applications/MAMP/bin/startApache.sh &" password mysql_pw user name mysql_user with administrator privileges          
    # Start MAMP's MySQL server
    do shell script "/Applications/MAMP/bin/startMysql.sh > /dev/null 2>&1"
end tell
```

How can insert some value in my db?

Comment: do shell script does not belong within a tell app "Finder" block.

Comment: @adayzdone `do shell script` **can** be inserted in any `tell` block ex: `tell application Finder to do shell script "ls"` - Off course you **don't need** (and I would avoid that as unecessary) to wrap it in a `tell` block. I think this is what you meant..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke directly **mysql** with AppleScript's `do shell script`statements.

`do shell script` lets you execute command script as you would enter them from the terminal. You then invoke **mysql** and send it commands:

(as the server is running)

```
do shell script "/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -u root --password=the_password \"INSERT INTO TABLE your_table (field_1, field_2) VALUES ('foo', 'bar');\" your_data_base_name"
```

---

Another (not free) solution is to use the software **Navicat for mySql**
It allows easy and efficient management of mySql databases from a GUI frontend.
It is also Apple-Scriptable.